# Fourier cosine series and sum help

Tags: fourier-series

I have been having some problems with the following problem:

Find the Fourier cosine series of the function $\vert\sin x\vert$ in the interval $(-\pi, \pi)$. Use it to find the sums

$$ \sum_{n\: =\: 1}^{\infty}\:\ \frac{1}{4n^2-1}$$  and $$ \sum_{n\: =\: 1}^{\infty}\:\ \frac{(-1)^n}{4n^2-1}$$

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

edit:I have gotten as far as working out the Fourier cosine series using the equations for cosine series

$$\phi (X) = 1/2 A_0 +  \sum_{n\: =\: 1}^{\infty}\:\ A_n \cos\left(\frac{n\pi x}{l}\right)$$ and 
$$A_m = \frac{2}{l} \int_{0}^{l} \phi (X) \cos\left(\frac{m\pi x}{l}\right) dx $$
I have found $$A_0 = \frac{4}{l}$$ but the rest of the question is a mess on my end and then I don't know how to relate the rest of it back to those sums.

Comment: related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/83150/evaluate-sum-limits-n-0-infty-frac14n21-by-using-complex-contour-in

Comment: Sorry I didn't know exactly how this worked, so I didn't really know about accepting answers, that will be remedied however I have tried doing the Fourier cosine series but I just don't see how the sums come in, I might be getting the wrong series though

Comment: Steve, could you include your attempts at a solution in your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

To find the Fourier coefficients of $|\sin(x)|$ note that
$$
\int_{-\pi}^\pi|\sin(x)|\cos(kx)\;\mathrm{d}x=2\int_0^\pi\sin(x)\cos(kx)\;\mathrm{d}x
$$
then use the trig identity $2\sin(x)\cos(y)=\sin(x+y)+\sin(x-y)$.

Once you get the Fourier coefficients you will probably see how to continue.  If not, append your work and say what is causing you difficulty.

Answer (score 6):

$f(x) = |\sin(x)| \quad \Rightarrow\quad f(x) = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{l l}
    -\sin(x) & \quad \forall x \in [- \pi, 0\space]\\
   \sin(x) & \quad \forall x \in [\space 0,\pi\space ]\\
  \end{array} \right.$

The Fourier coefficients associated are 
$$a_n= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) \cos(nx)\, dx = \frac{1}{\pi} \left[\int_{-\pi}^0 -\sin (x) \cos(nx)\, dx + \int_{0}^\pi \sin(x) \cos(nx)\, dx\right], \quad n \ge 0$$
$$b_n= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x) \sin(nx)\, dx = \frac{1}{\pi} \left[\int_{-\pi}^0 -\sin (x) \sin(nx)\, dx + \int_{0}^\pi \sin(x) \sin(nx)\, dx\right], \quad n \ge 1$$

All functions are integrable so we can go on and compute the expressions for $a_n$ and $b_n$.

$$a_n  = \cfrac{2 (\cos(\pi n)+1)}{\pi(1-n^2)}$$
$$b_n = 0$$
The $b_n = 0$ can be deemed obvious since the function $f(x) = |\sin(x)|$ is an [even function.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_function) and $a_n$ could have been calculated as $\displaystyle a_n= \frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^\pi f(x) \cos(nx)\, dx $ only because the function is [even](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_function).

The Fourier Series is $$\cfrac {a_0}{2} + \sum^{\infty}_{n=1}\left [ a_n \cos(nx) + b_n \sin (nx) \right ]$$
$$= \cfrac {2}{\pi}\left ( 1 + \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \cfrac{(\cos(\pi n)+1)}{(1-n^2)}\cos(nx)\right )$$
$$= \cfrac {2}{\pi}\left ( 1 + \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \cfrac{((-1)^n+1)}{(1-n^2)}\cos(nx)\right )$$
$$= \cfrac {2}{\pi}\left ( 1 + \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \cfrac{2}{(1-4n^2)}\cos(2nx)\right )$$
Since for an odd $n$, $((-1)^n+1) = 0$ and for an even $n$, $((-1)^n+1) = 2$

At this point we can't just assume the function is equal to its Fourier Series, it has to satisfy certain conditions. See [Convergence of Fourier series.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series)

Without wasting time, (***you still have to prove that it satisfies those conditions***) we assume the Fourier Series converges to our function i.e
$$f(x) = |\sin(x)| = \cfrac {2}{\pi}\left ( 1 + \sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \cfrac{2}{(1-4n^2)}\cos(2nx)\right )$$
Note that $x=0$ gives $\cos(2nx) = 1$ then 
$$f(0) = |\sin(0)| = \cfrac {2}{\pi}\left ( 1 + 2\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \cfrac{1}{(1-4n^2)}\right ) =0$$ which implies that
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \cfrac{1}{(1-4n^2)} = \cfrac {-1}{2}$$ and $$\boxed {\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \cfrac{1}{(4n^2 -1)}= -\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \cfrac{1}{(1-4n^2)} = \cfrac {1}{2}}$$

Observe again that when $x = \cfrac \pi 2$, $\cos (2nx) = cos(n \pi) = (-1)^n$, thus

$$f \left (\cfrac \pi 2 \right) = \left |\sin \left (\cfrac \pi 2\right )\right | = \cfrac {2}{\pi}\left ( 1 + 2\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \cfrac{(-1)^n}{(1-4n^2)}\right ) =1$$ which implies that
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \cfrac{(-1)^n}{(1-4n^2)} = \cfrac {1}{4}(\pi -2)$$ and $$\boxed {\displaystyle\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \cfrac{(-1)^n}{(4n^2 -1)}= -\sum^{\infty}_{n=1} \cfrac{(-1)^n}{(1-4n^2)} = \cfrac {1}{4}(2-\pi)}$$

Answer (score 4):

There is an alternative way to calculating the Fourier series as follows. The Fourier series for a periodic function $f(x)$ of period $2\pi$ (written $f(x) \sim \sum a_ne^{inx}$) is the sum
$$\sum a_n e^{inx}$$

where the Fourier coefficients $a_n$ are defined by $a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)e^{-inx} dx$. Now in your case, you can split the integral up into

$$\frac{1}{2\pi} \left(\int_{-\pi}^0 -\sin x e^{-inx} dx + \int_0^\pi \sin x e^{-inx} dx\right).$$

Now recall that $\sin x = \frac{e^{inx} - e^{-inx}}{2i}$ and chuck this into the integral to get the Fourier coefficient $a_n$ and hence you will obtain your Fourier series. You should get (I'm not spoiling anything because you can just chuck it into mathematica) that

$$f(x) \sim \sum_{n \in \Bbb{Z}} \frac{(1 + (-1)^n)e^{inx}}{\pi (1- n^2)} $$ Now to complete your problem in evaluating that sum, I suggest the following: The fourier series of $f(x)$ is absolutely convergent so we can say that

$$f(x) = \sum_{n \in \Bbb{Z}} \frac{(1 + (-1)^n)e^{inx}}{\pi (1- n^2)}. $$

For $n$ odd, the sum is zero so actually you can write

$$f(x) = \sum_{n \in \Bbb{Z}}  \frac{2e^{2inx}}{\pi (1- (2n)^2)}.$$

Now put $x = \pi$ so that $f(\pi) =0.$ Then we get that

$$\begin{eqnarray*} 0 = \sum_{n \in \Bbb{Z}}  \frac{2e^{2in\pi}}{\pi (1- (2n)^2)} &=& \sum_{n\in\Bbb{Z}} \frac{2}{\pi (1- (2n)^2)} \\
&=&\frac{2}{\pi} + \sum_{n\in\Bbb{Z}, n \geq 1}\frac{4}{\pi (1- (2n)^2)} \\
\implies \sum_{n\in\Bbb{Z}, n \geq 1}\frac{1}{4n^2 - 1} &=& \frac{2}{\pi}\cdot \frac{\pi}{4}\\
&=& \frac{1}{2}.
\end{eqnarray*}$$

The evaluation of the second sum is similar except that instead of substituting in $x = \pi$ you substitute in $x = \pi/2$.